# What sort of training is required to become a SQL Server DBA?

Tags: sql-server-2005

not sure if this question rely belongs here but what sort of training would someone need to become a SQL Server DBA? Going for a job as a junior DBA which includes training so just wondering what that might include?

Ta,

Jonesy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here you go](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-sql-server.aspx). I'd say that a Junior DBA ought to have the knowledge required to become certified MCTS on SQL Server, probably Exam 70-432 for a general DBA. Assuming that you mean MS SQL Server, and not some other SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the articles and blogs on http://sqlskills.com/  These are the real world things a DBA needs to be concerned with.  It probably wouldn't hurt to have a thorough understanding of different RAID levels

The best answer a DBA can often give when asked a question is, "it depends."